# Can't access term.php file from wp-admin directory?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, hosting, virtualmin

When I open my domain **[www.bhajanbook.in/wp-admin/term.php](http://www.bhajanbook.in/wp-admin/term.php)** it shows following error.

> **Forbidden**
>   You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/term.php on this server.

Please note that I have already performed following task for debugging error.

- I have checked `permissions` for a file and which is `644`. Its same like `edit-tags.php`. whereas `edit-tags.php` works fine.
- I also have checked ownership of file but its same for all files in `wp-admin` directory and which is `bhajanbook:bhajanbook`
- Please note that my hosting is `vps` and managed using `virtual min`
- I also have tried using deleting `term.php` and adding again from other `wp site` but no result.
- Also I have tried creating some other php file in `wp-admin` directory for `echo` simple message but same error.
- Below is my .htaccess file.

  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

  </IfModule>`

Please help me.

Comment: Any control with htaccess?

Comment: `.htaccess` is default file generated with WordPress.

Comment: there is no issue in .htaccess file. you have do the permission on wp-admin folder on your hosting server

Comment: @PriyankaModi `wp-admin` folder has permission `755 `.

Comment: Then you can remove the .htaccess file and create new .htaccess file

Comment: Tried removing and creating again but same problem.